# Java URL Connection times out on subsequent call

Tags: javascript, java

I am invoking java classes on a Javascript engine, so I am limited on what I can do.

The code works fine, but when I invoke the Javascript on a loop, it times out after the first invocation.

The code just downloads a ZIP from a url, and stores it to a path. Here is the full code:

```
var result = (function() {
    var URL = Packages.java.net.URL;
    var Files = Packages.java.nio.file.Files;
    var Paths = Packages.java.nio.file.Paths;
    var StandardCopyOption = Packages.java.nio.file.StandardCopyOption;

    var urlAddr = new URL(
            target_url
        );
    
     
    var connection = urlAddr.openConnection();
 
    connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
    connection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", bearer);
    
    connection.setReadTimeout(20*1000);
    
    connection.connect();

    Files.copy(connection.getInputStream(), Paths.get(file_path+new_filename+".zip"), StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
 

    return "";
}());
```

The error I am getting from the server:

> Java Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out: during call of javax.script.ScriptEngine.eval.

Before someone suggests, I cant get away from the java being called inside the javascript.

I thought it could be a connection being kept open.

UPDATE: this javascript for some reason is always taking 5 minutes to run....

UPDATE2: Files.copy seems to be the issue, since its the one taking the 5 minutes from the code.... the file is very small, and 5 min wouldnt justify

Comment: Do you mean *A Java script* or the programming language **JavaScript**?

Comment: @EmielZuurbier not sure I understood your question. I am invoking this javascript, which then invokes java classes

Comment: Seems the loop is the issue? Is the code for that here? If the second file isn't available for 5 minutes, perhaps its due to whatever blocking mechanism you're using.

Comment: the loop code is not here. I will add it, here

Comment: Most likely because you don't properly close the old connection. HttpURLConnection is pretty sensitive to old connections not properly closed (especially the InputStream. Besides the Java HttpURLConnection is to my experience pretty unstable and has some conditions where it is running into a dead-lock situation. Therefore my recommendation: If you can avoid it.

Comment: @Robert whats your recommendation?

Comment: If you can use apache commons httpclient library. Or if that is not possible and you are on Java 11+ try the new Java HttpClient: https://openjdk.java.net/groups/net/httpclient/intro.html

Comment: @Robert using httpclient library solved! I will accept your answer if you want to post one